# Preview dos dados antes de salvar no banco

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Estou a fazer um site de notícias em ASP.NET MVC 5 e surgiu a necessidade de ver o `Preview` da notícia antes de salvá-la no banco.

Com uma `action` de nome `Preview` posso mandar os dados para ela e enviar para uma `View` com o Design da página onde a notícia vai ser realmente mostrada, porém perco a tela de `Create`.

Como fazer com que abra uma nova Aba com a tela do `Preview` e a tela de `Create` continuasse intacta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu faria o seguinte:

- Uma `Action` chamada *Preview* com a seguinte assinatura:

  ```cs
  public ActionResult Preview(Noticia noticia) { ... }
  ```
- A *View* teria todos os atributos *hidden*:

  ```cs
  @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Titulo)
  @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ConteudoNoticia)
  ```
- Teria também as propriedades do Modelo escritas, como previsão:

  ```cs
  <div>@Model.Titulo</div>
  <article>@Model.ConteudoNoticia</article>
  ```
- Depois basta mandar via *POST* o Modelo novamente para outra `Action`. Pode ser a `Create` mesmo:

  ```cs
  public ActionResult Create(Noticia noticia) { ... }
  ```

Comment: Tentei fazer desse jeito, mas duas Actions com a messa assinatura o MVC não deixa.

public ActionResult Create(Noticia noticia)
        {}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Noticia noticia)
        {}

Comment: Então, mas repare que eu não usei o mesmo nome. Uma `Action` se chama `Preview` (por sinal, ela tem `[HttpPost]` também) e a outra é a `Create` (também com `[HttpPost]`).

Comment: E ainda na hora de construir seu form, você muda o target do form para `_blank` antes de submitar que aí vc vai ver em outra página e a atual

Comment: @cigano-morrison-mendez Eu tenho a Action Create por padrão, eu então envio esses dados para a Action Preview certo? Depois envio novamente para a Action Create, mas esta não me deixa receber com o objeto Noticia pelo fato do HttpPost do Create também receber este objeto e ter o mesmo nome. Pelo o menos aqui está dando erro.

Comment: @HermesAutran Aí é que está: como eu disse na resposta, você tem que colocar os campos em `hidden` e dentro de um `<form>` (preferencialmente usando `@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Noticias"))`) pra que você possa fazer um *POST* com os dados.